# SQL Cursor looping without declaring variables

Tags: sql-server

I have a flat table (all columns type is varchar) in sql server which contains 200 columns and out of which 100 columns will have numeric values including decimals. My requirement is loop all the columns and check if any column row contains alphanumeric or non-numeric value (example 100a0 etc.).

To achieve above scenario, in SQL we have cursor which helps to do the looping but to loop 100 columns i need to declare 100 variables and store the value like below
In SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_check_value]
AS

Declare     @col1 nvarchar(10),
            @col2 nvarchar(10),
            @col3 nvarchar(10),
            .
            .
            .
            @col100 nvarchar(10)

Declare mycursor cursor For

  select c1,c2,c3...c100 from temp

OPEN mycursor 
Fetch Next From mycursor Into @col1, @col2,@col3,...,col100

While @@Fetch_Status = 0 Begin

    --some update statment

Fetch Next From mycursor Into @col1, @col2,@col3,...,col100

End -- End of Fetch

Close mycursor
Deallocate mycursor
```

But, on the other side in oracle we have cursor but with some more handy way to handle above scenario.

In Oracle

```
create or replace procedure FooBar
as

cursor mydata is
select dog as d, cat as c, fish as f
  from temp;

begin
  for dr in mydata loop

    UPDATE foo SET dogs = dr.d, cats = dr.c, fishes = dr.f;

  end loop;
end;
```

So, can anybody help me to achieve above scenario in SQL without declaring 100 variables.

Thanks.

Comment: Before addressing the variables problem in the cursor, determine first if you need cursor at all. You might be able to do this in a set-based fashion.

Comment: @FelixPamittan, just to add more info the data in DB table will be populated from excel file with row number of excel file. So if any column row has non-numeric value then i need to log in table with row number. I think, looping is required here.

Comment: like you write it ... you are just looping the rows ... not the columns. do you need to update the columns that contain alphanumeric or non-numeric value ?

Comment: @dzomba, actully No, I have to check the value and log in log table.

Answer (score 0):

A starting point might be to select the columns from sys.tables:

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name, c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
```

Then based on the column names, you write dynamic sql to test the column for non-numeric values, and write output to temp table. I'm struggling to think of a set based way to do this - but having the set of columns is a starting point. Good Luck.